# Getting "undefined method `execute_script'" error after latest Chrome update

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

After upgrading to the latest stable Chrome version ***96.0.4664.55 (Official Build) (arm64)*** I am getting the   `undefined method execute_script for #<Hash:0x00007fb31432dba0> (NoMethodError)`
when I try to run my tests. I am using the Capybara framework, and I have recently updated to Selenium 4. I am using the following webdriver gems:
Gemfile

- gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 4.0.0"
- gem "webdrivers", "~> 4.6"

When I downgrade Chrome to 95.0.4638.69, everything works. Does anyone else have this issue, and know how to tackle it?

Comment: Not seeing the issue -- do you have a stacktrace or code example to show where it's coming from?